# Passing arraylist values to a jtable

Tags: java

I've been trying to populate a JTable from an object array, but nothing is showing up. Here is the method code that populates the table. The system.out.println enables me to check if the data is passed correctly, and there are values within the variables. This is from the interface:

```
public void populateTable(ArrayList<Outlet> outletList, String selection){
    f = new Fourth();
    for(int i = 0; i<outletList.size(); i++){
        if(outletList.get(i).getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(selection)){
            if(outletList.get(i).getStatus().equals("ACTIVE")){

                String bar = outletList.get(i).getBarangay();
                String code = Integer.toString(outletList.get(i).getCode());
                String name = outletList.get(i).getName();


                System.out.println(bar);
                System.out.println(code);
                System.out.println(name);

                Object[] data = {bar, code, name};   

                System.out.println("DATA: " + data[0].toString()); //correct
                System.out.println("DATA: " + data[1].toString()); //correct
                System.out.println("DATA: " + data[2].toString()); //correct

                f.getDtm().addRow(data);
            }   
        }   
    } 
}
```

This method is called when a user selects an item from a combobox. This panel is the page before the JTable is created:

```
 cityCombobox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            selCity1 = cityCombobox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(itr.next() == "Non-Citadel"){
                outlet.populateTable(outletList1, selCity1);
            }
        }
```

Here is my gui code for table and defaulttablemodel:

```
String[] columnNames = new String[]{"Barangay", "Name", "Code"};
    dtm = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
    pjpTable = new JTable(dtm);        

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(getPjpTable());
    tablePanel.add(new JScrollPane(getPjpTable()));

    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
    mainFrame.add(tablePanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Only the table headers appear, even if the data from the interface is displayed in the console. If anyone has a solution on how to correctly pass the data values to the JTable, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem with this code

```
String[] columnNames = new String[]{"Barangay", "Name", "Code"};
    dtm = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0); // here dtm is blank (No Data available at the time of Initializing.

    pjpTable = new JTable(dtm);      //JTable is Initialized with a Blank Data.
```

So, You Should fill `dtm` with blank data just before initializing `JTable` as `new JTable(dtm)`.

Here you are only updating `dtm` Object not try to redraw your table after new Rows has been added to the `dtm`.

```
f.getDtm().addRow(data);
```

So, Please when you call `event cityCombobox1.addActionListener`

```
 cityCombobox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            selCity1 = cityCombobox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(itr.next() == "Non-Citadel"){
                outlet.populateTable(outletList1, selCity1); // data is getting filled here.
            }
        }
```

Just after this you need to draw your `Table` Again. then only it will populate your Table Correctly.

> One More Suggestion.

`if(itr.next() == "Non-Citadel")` instead of `==` you should use `equals` method. because `==` is used to check reference of `String` Object while `equals` compare actual Value.

Answer (score 0):

you set to the table

```
dtm = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0); 

pjpTable = new JTable(dtm);
```

i guess **with only column names set**, try to fill the dtm **before** you set it to table. And i didnt understand what

```
 f = new Fourth();
```

means...

Comment: f = new Fourth(); is the gui class that holds the JTable and DefaultTableModel. Sorry for that! Will try your suggestion

Comment: Ok,  it smells a little bit for me also like bad design of a method (populateTable). make this method to return String [][] datas use String[] data instead of object data, also you may need to set the dtm to table after update.